# CNN: adding a third class improves the overall ranking of the network

Tags: conv-neural-network, image-segmentation, torch

I am working on a Convolutional Neural Network for classifying two classes of images whose difference between them is very small. Running the CNN (using PyTorch), it was able to correctly classify practically all of the labels belonging to the second class, but only half of the labels of the first class (the dataset was perfectly balanced). However, when I added a third class, completely different from the original two classes, the same CNN was able to perform much better, correctly classifying almost 100% of labels in the three classes. I am lacking the theoretical knowledge to understand why would this happen. The third class I added is completely different from the first two and I don't believe it has the ability of helping the CNN to better distinguish between them. What would explain this phenomena?